Write the length of the given curve as an integral and approximate it using binomial theorem.
Here's the full question -
The chain of a suspension bridge has the form of a curve -
$$x^2=b^2y/h$$
Write down the length of the curve in the form of an integral.
Show that when h is very smaller than b, the radical under the integral sign can be expanded by binomial theorem and that the length of the chain is approximately -
$$2b + 4h^2/3b$$
It's from my maths textbook. So, I tried finding the length of the curve from (0,0) to any point (x,y) on the curve.
First, find $dy/dx$ -
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 2hx/b^2$$
Now, length of the curve (say s) will be given by the formula -
$$s = \int_0^x \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \ \mathrm dx$$
After simplification,
$$s = 1/2hb^2\left[\frac{2hx\sqrt{b^4+4h^2x^2}}2 + \frac{b^4\log(2hx + \sqrt{b^4 + 4h^2x^2}}2\right]\bigg\rvert_0^x$$
I am stuck here. How to apply binomial expansion to this and get the approximate length of the chain? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

@YvesDaoust thanks. still getting x in the final answer. do you think the integrand has wrong limits?

@YvesDaoust got it. thanks a lot.
